# How do I find @types for my chrome extension code in typescript?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, typescript-typings

I am trying to migrate my Chrome extension to TypeScript and have a big number of errors related to lack of `@types`. I think if someone sheds light on how to solve one, most of them will get solved.

So I have this generic error handler:

```
export function fsErrorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  }
}
```

which of course complains about `FileError`.

These are my `@types` already in place:

```
chrome
filesystem
filewriter
jquery
```

As much as I understood from the [HTML5 FileSystem API book](https://books.google.se/books?id=j_guWrO8ih0C&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR&source=bl&ots=j8QJt282tS&sig=sfAxYG9iRGuWrnbcXKPFYPkafqw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqqYnE24XTAhWSKiwKHe1mAmEQ6AEISTAI#v=onepage&q=FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR&f=false), the FileError is part of File API, so with @types/filesystem in place, it should be recognized by WebStorm... What am I missing?

Another missing type is `navigator`, but I found info that it has been merged to lib.d.ts so it should be recognized as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError FileError is a obsolete feature. That is why you are not found this on types definitions.

Try change your code to use the new DOM4 `DOMError` interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMError

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'll do it in a free moment. Meanwhile I just copied interface from Cordova as a quick and dirty workaround.